# Reading structure tags from a header file?

Tags: c, json, struct, header

So I wanted to configure different structures for which I have a header file such as:

**header.h**

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t hola;
    uint32_t adios;

}Signal_t;

typedef struct
{
    bool            goodbye; 
    uint32_t        hello;

} FrameTx_t;
```

In order to do so, at some point, within my source code, I will need to detect which kind of structure is to be configured by the received text. 
id. est: If I have a JSON file that goes somewhere along:

**JSON_File.txt**

```
{"Signal_t" : 
    {
        "hola" :  1024,
        "adios" : 555555 
    }
}
```

I need to recognize that the to-be-configured structure is of type Signal_t.

For now I have developed a simple code in which, after parsing the text, I can obtain the name of the structure in a string format, and then I created the following function to determine which structure is to be configured:

**Code.c**

```
int structure_Select(char* structName, int sizeOfStructName) {
char Signal_tName[] = "Signal_t";
char FrameTx_tName[] = "FrameTx_t";
int idx=0;

if ((sizeof(Signal_tName) - 1) == sizeOfStructName) {
    for (idx = 0;idx < sizeOfStructName;idx++) {
        if (Signal_tName[idx] != structName[idx]) {
            break;
        }

    }
    if (idx == sizeOfStructName) { 
        printf("%s", Signal_tName);
        return 0; 


    }
}
if ((sizeof(FrameTx_tName) - 1) == sizeOfStructName) {
    for (idx = 0;idx < sizeOfStructName;idx++) {
        if (FrameTx_tName[idx] != structName[idx]) {
            break;
        }

    }
    if (idx == sizeOfStructName) {
        printf("%s", FrameTx_tName);
        return 1;


    }
} 
}
```

I can assure you it works; it just does not go as "automatic" as I would like it to be...
 I would like for the program to be able to read the header file and automatically recognize: "Oh okay, so I'm dealing with a Signal_t data type, I'm gonna then read two different data from the stream and assign data1 to Signal_t.hola and data2 to Signal_t.adios"

The assignation is clearly not a problem; only determining from an existing structure within a file the name of it or a way to differentiate between structs. 
So far I've thought about the following possibilities outside of what I already have, but I'm cycled within it:

o Create a mini "C-structure parser" function

o Is there ANY way to get the name of a structure tag within C that I don't know of?

I'm open to suggestions, whether it's just ideas that I could work on and I'm not seeing or if any of you has dealed with a similar issue in the past and instead of using a list of char variables, actually reads the header file for the structure names... thanks in advance!

.

.

.

TL;DR: Is there any way to read structures' tags from a header file as a string?

**Edit:** This is what I mean with structure tag/type alias:

```
//structure to get a rectangle
typedef struct { 
int left; 
int bottom; 
int right; 
int top; 
} rect_t; //this rect_t is what I mean by structure tag... 
//I checked the name and it should be type alias***
```

Comment: Think ahead, what will you do if it is possible and you find a way of doing it. I think you will then find out that what you are actually trying to achieve in the end will be impossible in spite of that. Read this to get thinking https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Makes sense haha, but that's exactly the problem.... I found a solution for a problem and I'm cycled over it...without it being the entire definitive solution for my entire definitive problem :|

Comment: What you have would look a whole lot more pleasant if you just used `strcmp`...

Comment: I tried strcmp at first, but the problem with it is that the input string into my function is of size 1024, while the target string, for example Signal_t is size 9... strcmp from what I understand does not work if you have two different-sized strings. **Edit:** The input string size is 1024 bc  that same variable is used to receive other text once every cycle; this comparison is only done the first time

Comment: @Cuboscar95 Of course `strcmp` works on different sized strings. What gave you the impression it didn't? You can confirm with a simple test `printf("%d\n", strcmp("hello", "hellothere");`

Comment: No, sorry, Brainfart! hehe I meant that if I would do as you said, those two strings will always be different, and I would need the exact same string... nevertheless I will check strcmp again, maybe I misunderstood the return values, and it could make my code WAY cleaner as u said! Thank you for that :)

Comment: I don't get your question. As other people pointed out in the comments, your whole unreadable `if` blocks can be replaced by `if(strcmp(structName, Signal_tName) == 0) { ... }`. You are over complicating things for no reason. What do you mean by *read structures' tags from a header file*? What is a structure tag?

Comment: @Cuboscar95 what about `strncmp` ?

Comment: @John3136 You are right, I forgot about `strncmp`, and it fits just right to my program; I just kept one if statement, plus another one for strncmp. Thank you! 
@Pablo I editted my question for you to see what I mean by struct type... you are right, the term isn't structure tag, that is something else... the correct name for what I seek is structure type alias, being it, in the case for my edit, **rect_t**. I wish to recognize that text "rect_t" but straight from the **header.h** file